# What is a good book for learning math from the very basic?

Tags: functions

I am an undergraduate student. Lately i realized that i donot have any basic on mathematics, not even elementary level!!can you recommend some books for learning math from the ground up-- from rather basic math to advanced math (middle school -> graduate school) which could help review the basics. 
Thanks

Comment: Be a little more specific or you can expect people on here to close this thread for being too broad. Would you like to begin with basic arithmetic, algebra I, or what? Education level of middle school varies by grade and location.

Comment: I think [_Algebra The Easy Way_](https://books.google.com/books/about/Algebra_the_Easy_Way.html?id=RiX-TJLiQv0C) (and its sequels on trigonometry and calculus) are good, but I don't know if you want to start earlier than that.

Comment: The notion of "elementary level" is relative.  Presumably you took some math in high school (or the equivalent).  Should you require middle school remedial math courses, this would be a pretty specialized task.  It's not a problem that can be addressed without counseling.

Answer (score 2):

Gelfand's series of books are excellent and require only basic knowledge of primary school algebra to begin. I assume you want something cheap and these are pretty cheap. I found the exposition really clear and it has a conversational tone which makes the material easy to digest, I think.

[Trigonometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639144)

[Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773)

[Method of Coordinates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425657)

[Functions and Graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486425649)

I suggest the following order- Algebra, Trigonometry, Method of Coordinates and then Functions and Graphs.

Be warned that these do not contain a solution set though. You might want to pair these books with online exercises from [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/) and a book like [Schaum's precalculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071795596) which contain problems that can help you to get to grips with things.

Answer (score 2):

I know very little about books concerning introductory "computational" mathematics, but I do have one piece of advice that has at least helped me.

Before moving on to proof based mathematics, my school required me to take a class called "Fundamentals of Advanced Math." The class used the book "Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics" by Chartrand, Polimeni and Zhang. This class was a prerequisite for all "upper level" undergraduate math courses.

The book covers various methods of writing mathematical proofs and additionally applies these methods to (very elementary) problems in a variety of fields including Topology, Number theory, etc. The book (and class) helped tremendously in my understanding of what followed.

There are many books like this one out there, so when you reach this level I recommend investing time in the study of actual proof writing. After you obtain a sufficient grasp on proof writing, it becomes very difficult to recommend books as they become very specialized.